# How can a superclass in Dart access its own methods if they have been overridden?

Tags: dart, methods, overriding, superclass

Here is a simplified version of a problem I have.

```
class A {
  void a1() => xxx();
  void xxx() => print('A xxx');
}

class B extends A {
  void b1() => super.xxx();
  void b2() => xxx();
  void xxx() => print('B xxx');
}

void main() {
  B().a1();
  B().b1();
  B().b2();
}
```

Here is the output.

B xxx
A xxx
B xxx

I need class A to be able to access xxx in class A even if xxx has been overridden. How do I achieve this? Class B can access it using super but I can't find a way for class A to access its own method.

Comment: It took ages to post this question. I originally had "A.xxx" and "B.xxx" printed as output and I kept getting an improperly formatted code error. phew, I'm starving.

Comment: I don't think that is possible since the point of overloading is to make it so `A` does not know about it. If you have a method you don't want to allow overloading, you can make a private method (prefix name with `_`) which cannot be overloaded by classes in another library (so, yes, you can still do it if both classes are in same library).

Comment: @julemand101 I think a situation where class B can access a method in class A using super, but class A cannot access its own method is wrong. Surely class A has more right to access its own methods than class B.